# Recover corrupted java file

Tags: java, eclipse, recovery

I tried to reimport my android project on eclipse to solve a problem but I accidently overwrote all my files in the project. All of them had been corrupted which means their size is now 0B...
I tried to use Local History but it's useless since my project is no longer in my workspace, same for .metadata.
I also tried to use Recuva (Software for recovering files) which see my files with their real size but when I try recover them, their size is always 0B...
I lost about 7 days of work and I don't really want to rewrite my code using Java Decompiler...
So my question is, is there any solution to recover that files ?

Comment: *"Thanks in advance for your answers !"*  What is your question?  I can think of a few *"Are my sources lost?"* Yes.  *"Should I use a CVS?"*  Yes.  *"Is there a point to crying over lost source?"* No.  *"Will it be easier to reconstruct code from a decompiler, or just rewrite it?"*  The latter.  -- Now, if none of those are your question, think one up & add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17743708/edit).

Comment: Are you telling us that you are working WITH NO remote versioning system, NO local versioning system, NO manual backups (zip files, etc), AND you override an entire, unbackupped project without noticing it until it is too late ? I see this week of work lost as an opportunity to grow... P.S: it is off topic here, you should try on super user, and good luck

Comment: Don't tell me you don't use a VCS?

Comment: comment edited, sorry
@AndreaLigios Yes I see it this way too, I have not enough experience on developping project to notice what you noticed.

Comment: This happens once to everybody, but only once.

Comment: Not a programming question, and not related to Java.  Ask over on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (after searching there first, for dupes of your question).

Comment: @Hot Licks I'll take care on my future questions, it's non-java related but I was meaning I wanted to recover a .java file first in fact.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote 200 lines of code and suddenly system restarted. I lost all code. But I recovered data from eclipse's local history. Right click on the file -->replace with-->previous from Local History

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse has a local history, although by default it's set very low - one of my first tasks when setting up a new development machine is to up the values (in addition to my other version control) [image]

If you do have a history you can right click on your class, and select compare with local history.

Comment: Woah ! Eclipse user from many years and never noticed that feature ! Definitely a deserved +1

Comment: Thanks. The newer versions even have a check-box now that allows unlimited history

Answer (score 1):

You could try decompiling with something like [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui). It might not be as onerous as you think. Obfuscators exist for a reason.

Comment: I've already done it, and I plan to rewrite it using that base.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really programming question, but i had similar situation and "Mini Tool Power Data Recovery" tool helped me (it is paid tool, free version exists, but  maybe you can search in this direction and find something open source). I tried some another tools then, but with no results.